# Merge VOB files via command line?

Tags: command-line, video

Is it possible to merge two (or more) video files from the command line? In Windows, one could do this:

```
copy /b VTS_01_1.vob + VTS_01_2.vob + VTS_01_3.vob + VTS_01_4.vob Output.vob
```

I find this to be much easier and faster than using a dedicated GUI program. Is there an equivalent in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
cat VTS_01_*.vob > output.vob
```

Improved version (this will show a progress bar):

```
cat VTS_O1_*.VOB | pv | dd of=output.vob
```

Similar to the 2nd:

```
 pv VTS_01_*.vob > output.vob
```

---

Oh and you could also `mv` the output.vob to `.mpeg` and have it play in VLC or another videoplayer.

---

Using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:VTS_01_1.VOB|VTS_01_2.VOB|VTS_01_3.VOB|VTS_01_4.VOB" -f mpeg -c copy output.mpeg
```

---

The methods using `cat` do NOT interpret the files and just add them together. 1 typical thing you will notice is a slight hickup when the player goes from 1 to the next VOB. Avidemux (GUI), for instance, will also demux(is that the correct word?) the files so it is a smoother experience.

---

If you receive the error message

> ac3 in MPEG-1 system streams is not widely supported, consider using the vob or the dvd muxer to force a MPEG-2 program stream

then you will need to specify DVD as the output format by adjusting the above ffmpeg command with `... -f dvd ...`.

Comment: Interesting. I can see that the end result will be identical to what the OP claims works with Windows but would the result be playable? I'll admit I don't work much with VOB files preferring MKV format (via `ffmpeg` ) and tools like `mkvmerge` for merging

Comment: cat works for merging the files. It does not care about chapters and the other stuff if it is a DVD ;)

Comment: Curious why `cat` instead of `dd if=`?  Is that something you could add to the description if you don't think it'd be too distracting?

Answer (score 10):

If you are interested in using FFmpeg (which opens up the possibility of concatenating *other* media types less tractable than .vob) you can use the following for your example:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:VTS_01_1.vob|VTS_01_2.vob|VTS_01_3.vob|VTS_01_4.vob" -c copy output.vob
```

I confess that FFmpeg is a 'dedicated' program which you would prefer not to use but note that other media types may require *transcoding* before concatenation and in these cases FFmpeg's services will be required...

**References:**

- [FFmpeg trac: Concatenating media files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I use FFmpeg quite a bit ... I've edited the question to include the word 'GUI', which was what I was thinking of as an alternative.

Comment: Tried this, and got a VOB that was significantly smaller than the `cat`ed version while containing multiple incomplete passages (video and audio hiccups). A simple `cat` worked quite well instead.

Answer (score 7):

## VOB

VOB requires special care due their potentially complex structure and timestamp incongruities, so blindly concatenating these may have unexpected results. You should use DVD structure aware tools for this format.

The FFmpeg source code comes with a tool (`tools/dvd2concat`) that utilizes `lsdvd` to produce a proper concatenation script:

```
cd ffmpeg/tools
./dvd2concat path/to/dvd/structure > file.concat
ffmpeg -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist subfile,file,concat -f concat -i file.concat -map 0 -c copy -f dvd output.vob
```

## Other file types

`ffmpeg` has three methods to concatenate:

- [concat demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) - For general concatenation or for doing so without re-encoding.
- [concat protocol](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#concat) - Similar to just using `cat`. For formats that can be simply joined with no issues (MPEG-1, MPEG-2 PS, DV, rawvideo).
- [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) - Useful if you are performing any filtering (scaling,  overlays, etc).

Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: Concatenate](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) and [FFmpeg FAQ: How can I concatenate video files?](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-concatenate-video-files_003f)

Comment: is [mkvmerge](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html) an another option?

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `cat` (concatenate) command for this.

In your case:

```
cat VTS_01_1.vob VTS_01_2.vob VTS_01_3.vob VTS_01_4.vob > Output.vob
```